# Zoom in, zoom out, and pan tools cannot be toggled off in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, zoom

When I select the Pan Map, zoom in, and zoom out tools in the QGIS toolbar (version 2.18.16), I cannot toggle it off after using it. In efforts to toggle a tool from the toolbar off after using it, I have tried clicking the tool again and pressing escape but none works.

How do I toggle off a tool like pan or zoom in QGIS?

Comment: Select some other tool.

Comment: Actually, QGIS map canvas must always have an active map tool. You should activate another map tool. if it doesn't work , you can deactivate it by python console. Run that code: `iface.mapCanvas().mapTool().deactivate()`